# Is there a way to move/remove "system settings" from the shut-down menu?

Tags: system-settings

In 11.04 "System settings" is at the bottom of window and when I try to shut down the computer I always click that instead of the shut down button.

So is there a way to remove this system settings button?!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can easily disable it by running the following from a `gnome-terminal`:

```
sudo rm /usr/share/indicators/session/applications/gnomecc.desktop
```

This will simply delete the link to the GNOME Control Center. Then logout/login or restart. Should be away after that ;-)

However, it will be in a different way in Oneiric [as replied here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/746784) by Mr. Shuttleworth himself. ;-)